# Ignoring .DS_Store watchdog

Tags: python, python-3.x, watchdog, python-watchdog

I want to ignore `.DS_Store` files in all the directories using watchdog, but I cant seem to make it work.

I tried using this with multiple patterns which might work, however it didn't help at all.

```
PatternMatchingEventHandler(ignore_patterns=["*/.DS_Store", "./.DS_Store", ".DS_Store", "DS_Store"])
```

Still prints out this

```
2021-04-08 08:53:40 - queue_event <FileModifiedEvent: event_type=modified, src_path='/Users/path/.DS_Store', is_directory=False>
```

** UPDATE **

I also tried using regexes like this, which didn't help neither.

```
RegexMatchingEventHandler(ignore_regexes=[".*DS_Store.*"])
```

Comment: Perhaps you need the double star glob pattern to match any number of directories, i.e. `**/.DS_Store`

Comment: @JamesElderfield did not help, but thanks!